# Umbraco 7.5.4 installation error: Invalid Objectname CmsContent

Tags: installation, nuget, umbraco, umbraco7

I've installed umbracoCms((version 7.5.4)) nuget package to my empty mvc project (.Net 4.6.2, vs2015). Then, I run the project and it opened installation page. Then I customized connection and used a connectionstring for an ms sql 2016 database. I didn't select any starter website and I've got the error below:

```
The database failed to upgrade. ERROR: The database configuration failed with the following message: Invalid object name 'cmsContent'. Please check log file for additional information (can be found in '/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt')
```

What should I do now ?

Steps for Installation:

1-

[image]

2- After clicked to Customize:

[image]

3- After selecting "Custom connection string" for Database Type:

[image]

4- After clicked to button Continue:
[image]

5- Full Error after clicked "No thanks, I do not want to install a starter website" link:

```
2016-11-28 22:31:20,810 [P1436/D4/T19] ERROR Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UmbracoDatabase - Database exception occurred
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'cmsContent'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in c:\Code\github\SamSaffron\MiniProfiler\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 235
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteReaderWithRetry>b__3()
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy cmdRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy conRetryPolicy)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.<Query>d__7`1.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:d8b48152-6c2e-4768-9ba4-c294f060220e
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
 2016-11-28 22:31:20,889 [P1436/D4/T19] ERROR Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - Database configuration failed
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'cmsContent'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in c:\Code\github\SamSaffron\MiniProfiler\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 235
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteReaderWithRetry>b__3()
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy cmdRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy conRetryPolicy)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.PetaPocoCommandExtensions.ExecuteReaderWithRetry(IDbCommand command)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.<Query>d__7`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.Upgrades.TargetVersionSevenTwoZero.AddMissingForeignKeyForContentType.Up()
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationBase.GetUpExpressions(IMigrationContext context)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner.InitializeMigrations(List`1 migrations, Database database, DatabaseProviders databaseProvider, Boolean isUpgrade)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner.Execute(Database database, DatabaseProviders databaseProvider, Boolean isUpgrade)
   at Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner.Execute(Database database, Boolean isUpgrade)
   at Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext.UpgradeSchemaAndData(IMigrationEntryService migrationEntryService)
ClientConnectionId:d8b48152-6c2e-4768-9ba4-c294f060220e
Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
 2016-11-28 22:31:20,923 [P1436/D4/T19] INFO  Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - The database schema validation produced the following summary: 
The following tables were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:
umbracoNode,cmsContentType,cmsTemplate,cmsContent,cmsContentVersion,cmsDocument,cmsDocumentType,cmsDataType,cmsDataTypePreValues,cmsDictionary,umbracoLanguage,cmsLanguageText,umbracoDomains,umbracoLog,cmsMacro,cmsMacroProperty,cmsMemberType,cmsMember,cmsMember2MemberGroup,cmsContentXml,cmsPreviewXml,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,cmsPropertyType,cmsPropertyData,umbracoRelationType,umbracoRelation,cmsTags,cmsTagRelationship,umbracoUserType,umbracoUser,cmsTaskType,cmsTask,cmsContentType2ContentType,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,umbracoUser2app,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,umbracoUser2NodePermission,umbracoAccess,umbracoAccessRule,umbracoCacheInstruction,umbracoExternalLogin,umbracoMigration,umbracoDeployChecksum,umbracoDeployDependency,umbracoRedirectUrl

The following columns were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:
umbracoNode,id,umbracoNode,trashed,umbracoNode,parentID,umbracoNode,nodeUser,umbracoNode,level,umbracoNode,path,umbracoNode,sortOrder,umbracoNode,uniqueID,umbracoNode,text,umbracoNode,nodeObjectType,umbracoNode,createDate,cmsContentType,pk,cmsContentType,nodeId,cmsContentType,alias,cmsContentType,icon,cmsContentType,thumbnail,cmsContentType,description,cmsContentType,isContainer,cmsContentType,allowAtRoot,cmsTemplate,pk,cmsTemplate,nodeId,cmsTemplate,alias,cmsTemplate,design,cmsContent,pk,cmsContent,nodeId,cmsContent,contentType,cmsContentVersion,id,cmsContentVersion,ContentId,cmsContentVersion,VersionId,cmsContentVersion,VersionDate,cmsDocument,nodeId,cmsDocument,published,cmsDocument,documentUser,cmsDocument,versionId,cmsDocument,text,cmsDocument,releaseDate,cmsDocument,expireDate,cmsDocument,updateDate,cmsDocument,templateId,cmsDocument,newest,cmsDocumentType,contentTypeNodeId,cmsDocumentType,templateNodeId,cmsDocumentType,IsDefault,cmsDataType,pk,cmsDataType,nodeId,cmsDataType,propertyEditorAlias,cmsDataType,dbType,cmsDataTypePreValues,id,cmsDataTypePreValues,datatypeNodeId,cmsDataTypePreValues,value,cmsDataTypePreValues,sortorder,cmsDataTypePreValues,alias,cmsDictionary,pk,cmsDictionary,id,cmsDictionary,parent,cmsDictionary,key,umbracoLanguage,id,umbracoLanguage,languageISOCode,umbracoLanguage,languageCultureName,cmsLanguageText,pk,cmsLanguageText,languageId,cmsLanguageText,UniqueId,cmsLanguageText,value,umbracoDomains,id,umbracoDomains,domainDefaultLanguage,umbracoDomains,domainRootStructureID,umbracoDomains,domainName,umbracoLog,id,umbracoLog,userId,umbracoLog,NodeId,umbracoLog,Datestamp,umbracoLog,logHeader,umbracoLog,logComment,cmsMacro,id,cmsMacro,macroUseInEditor,cmsMacro,macroRefreshRate,cmsMacro,macroAlias,cmsMacro,macroName,cmsMacro,macroScriptType,cmsMacro,macroScriptAssembly,cmsMacro,macroXSLT,cmsMacro,macroCacheByPage,cmsMacro,macroCachePersonalized,cmsMacro,macroDontRender,cmsMacro,macroPython,cmsMacroProperty,id,cmsMacroProperty,editorAlias,cmsMacroProperty,macro,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertySortOrder,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertyAlias,cmsMacroProperty,macroPropertyName,cmsMemberType,pk,cmsMemberType,NodeId,cmsMemberType,propertytypeId,cmsMemberType,memberCanEdit,cmsMemberType,viewOnProfile,cmsMember,nodeId,cmsMember,Email,cmsMember,LoginName,cmsMember,Password,cmsMember2MemberGroup,Member,cmsMember2MemberGroup,MemberGroup,cmsContentXml,nodeId,cmsContentXml,xml,cmsPreviewXml,nodeId,cmsPreviewXml,versionId,cmsPreviewXml,timestamp,cmsPreviewXml,xml,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,id,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,contenttypeNodeId,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,text,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,sortorder,cmsPropertyTypeGroup,uniqueID,cmsPropertyType,id,cmsPropertyType,dataTypeId,cmsPropertyType,contentTypeId,cmsPropertyType,propertyTypeGroupId,cmsPropertyType,Alias,cmsPropertyType,Name,cmsPropertyType,sortOrder,cmsPropertyType,mandatory,cmsPropertyType,validationRegExp,cmsPropertyType,Description,cmsPropertyType,UniqueID,cmsPropertyData,id,cmsPropertyData,contentNodeId,cmsPropertyData,versionId,cmsPropertyData,propertytypeid,cmsPropertyData,dataInt,cmsPropertyData,dataDecimal,cmsPropertyData,dataDate,cmsPropertyData,dataNvarchar,cmsPropertyData,dataNtext,umbracoRelationType,id,umbracoRelationType,dual,umbracoRelationType,parentObjectType,umbracoRelationType,childObjectType,umbracoRelationType,name,umbracoRelationType,alias,umbracoRelation,id,umbracoRelation,parentId,umbracoRelation,childId,umbracoRelation,relType,umbracoRelation,datetime,umbracoRelation,comment,cmsTags,id,cmsTags,tag,cmsTags,ParentId,cmsTags,group,cmsTagRelationship,nodeId,cmsTagRelationship,tagId,cmsTagRelationship,propertyTypeId,umbracoUserType,id,umbracoUserType,userTypeAlias,umbracoUserType,userTypeName,umbracoUserType,userTypeDefaultPermissions,umbracoUser,id,umbracoUser,userDisabled,umbracoUser,userNoConsole,umbracoUser,userType,umbracoUser,startStructureID,umbracoUser,startMediaID,umbracoUser,userName,umbracoUser,userLogin,umbracoUser,userPassword,umbracoUser,userEmail,umbracoUser,userLanguage,umbracoUser,securityStampToken,umbracoUser,failedLoginAttempts,umbracoUser,lastLockoutDate,umbracoUser,lastPasswordChangeDate,umbracoUser,lastLoginDate,cmsTaskType,id,cmsTaskType,alias,cmsTask,closed,cmsTask,id,cmsTask,taskTypeId,cmsTask,nodeId,cmsTask,parentUserId,cmsTask,userId,cmsTask,DateTime,cmsTask,Comment,cmsContentType2ContentType,parentContentTypeId,cmsContentType2ContentType,childContentTypeId,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,Id,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,AllowedId,cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,SortOrder,umbracoUser2app,user,umbracoUser2app,app,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,userId,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,nodeId,umbracoUser2NodeNotify,action,umbracoUser2NodePermission,userId,umbracoUser2NodePermission,nodeId,umbracoUser2NodePermission,permission,umbracoAccess,id,umbracoAccess,nodeId,umbracoAccess,loginNodeId,umbracoAccess,noAccessNodeId,umbracoAccess,createDate,umbracoAccess,updateDate,umbracoAccessRule,id,umbracoAccessRule,accessId,umbracoAccessRule,ruleValue,umbracoAccessRule,ruleType,umbracoAccessRule,createDate,umbracoAccessRule,updateDate,umbracoCacheInstruction,id,umbracoCacheInstruction,utcStamp,umbracoCacheInstruction,jsonInstruction,umbracoCacheInstruction,originated,umbracoExternalLogin,id,umbracoExternalLogin,userId,umbracoExternalLogin,loginProvider,umbracoExternalLogin,providerKey,umbracoExternalLogin,createDate,umbracoMigration,id,umbracoMigration,name,umbracoMigration,createDate,umbracoMigration,version,umbracoDeployChecksum,id,umbracoDeployChecksum,entityType,umbracoDeployChecksum,entityGuid,umbracoDeployChecksum,entityPath,umbracoDeployChecksum,localChecksum,umbracoDeployChecksum,compositeChecksum,umbracoDeployDependency,sourceId,umbracoDeployDependency,targetId,umbracoDeployDependency,mode,umbracoRedirectUrl,id,umbracoRedirectUrl,contentKey,umbracoRedirectUrl,createDateUtc,umbracoRedirectUrl,url,umbracoRedirectUrl,urlHash

The following constraints (Primary Keys, Foreign Keys and Indexes) were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:
FK_umbracoNode_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsContentType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsTemplate_umbracoNode,FK_cmsContent_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsContent_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsContentVersion_cmsContent_nodeId,FK_cmsDocument_cmsContent_nodeId,FK_cmsDocument_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsDocument_cmsTemplate_nodeId,FK_cmsDocumentType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsDocumentType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsDocumentType_cmsTemplate_nodeId,FK_cmsDataType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsDataTypePreValues_cmsDataType_nodeId,FK_cmsDictionary_cmsDictionary_id,FK_cmsLanguageText_umbracoLanguage_id,FK_cmsLanguageText_cmsDictionary_id,FK_umbracoDomains_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsMacroProperty_cmsMacro_id,FK_cmsMemberType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsMemberType_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsMember_cmsContent_nodeId,FK_cmsMember_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsMember2MemberGroup_cmsMember_nodeId,FK_cmsMember2MemberGroup_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsContentXml_cmsContent_nodeId,FK_cmsPreviewXml_cmsContent_nodeId,FK_cmsPreviewXml_cmsContentVersion_VersionId,FK_cmsPropertyTypeGroup_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_cmsDataType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_cmsContentType_nodeId,FK_cmsPropertyType_cmsPropertyTypeGroup_id,FK_cmsPropertyData_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsPropertyData_cmsPropertyType_id,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoNode,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoNode1,FK_umbracoRelation_umbracoRelationType_id,FK_cmsTags_cmsTags,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsContent,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsTags_id,FK_cmsTagRelationship_cmsPropertyType,FK_umbracoUser_umbracoUserType_id,FK_cmsTask_cmsTaskType_id,FK_cmsTask_umbracoNode_id,FK_cmsTask_umbracoUser,FK_cmsTask_umbracoUser1,FK_cmsContentType2ContentType_umbracoNode_parent,FK_cmsContentType2ContentType_umbracoNode_child,FK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType_cmsContentType,FK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType_cmsContentType1,FK_umbracoUser2app_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoUser2NodePermission_umbracoUser_id,FK_umbracoUser2NodePermission_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id1,FK_umbracoAccess_umbracoNode_id2,FK_umbracoAccessRule_umbracoAccess_id,FK_umbracoDeployDependency_umbracoDeployChecksum_id1,FK_umbracoDeployDependency_umbracoDeployChecksum_id2,FK_umbracoRedirectUrl_umbracoNode_uniqueID,PK_structure,PK_cmsContentType,PK_cmsTemplate,PK_cmsContent,PK_cmsContentVersion,PK_cmsDocument,PK_cmsDocumentType,PK_cmsDataType,PK_cmsDataTypePreValues,PK_cmsDictionary,PK_umbracoLanguage,PK_cmsLanguageText,PK_umbracoDomains,PK_umbracoLog,PK_cmsMacro,PK_cmsMacroProperty,PK_cmsMemberType,PK_cmsMember,PK_cmsMember2MemberGroup,PK_cmsContentXml,PK_cmsContentPreviewXml,PK_cmsPropertyTypeGroup,PK_cmsPropertyType,PK_cmsPropertyData,PK_umbracoRelationType,PK_umbracoRelation,PK_cmsTags,PK_cmsTagRelationship,PK_umbracoUserType,PK_user,PK_cmsTaskType,PK_cmsTask,PK_cmsContentType2ContentType,PK_cmsContentTypeAllowedContentType,PK_user2app,PK_umbracoUser2NodeNotify,PK_umbracoUser2NodePermission,PK_umbracoAccess,PK_umbracoAccessRule,PK_umbracoCacheInstruction,PK_umbracoExternalLogin,PK_umbracoMigration,PK_umbracoDeployChecksum,PK_umbracoDeployDependency,PK_umbracoRedirectUrl,IX_umbracoNodeTrashed,IX_umbracoNodeParentId,IX_umbracoNodeUniqueID,IX_umbracoNodeObjectType,IX_cmsContentType,IX_cmsContentType_icon,IX_cmsTemplate_nodeId,IX_cmsContent,IX_cmsContentVersion_ContentId,IX_cmsContentVersion_VersionId,IX_cmsDocument,IX_cmsDocument_published,IX_cmsDocument_newest,IX_cmsDataType_nodeId,IX_cmsDictionary_id,IX_umbracoLanguage_languageISOCode,IX_umbracoLog,IX_cmsMacroPropertyAlias,IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias,IX_cmsPropertyTypeGroupUniqueID,IX_cmsPropertyTypeUniqueID,IX_cmsPropertyData,IX_cmsPropertyData_1,IX_cmsPropertyData_2,IX_cmsPropertyData_3,IX_cmsTags,IX_umbracoUser_userLogin,IX_cmsTaskType_alias,IX_computerName,IX_umbracoServer_isActive,IX_umbracoAccess_nodeId,IX_umbracoAccessRule,IX_umbracoMigration,IX_umbracoDeployChecksum,IX_umbracoRedirectUrl

The following indexes were found in the database, but are not in the current schema:
IX_umbracoNodeTrashed,IX_umbracoNodeParentId,IX_umbracoNodeUniqueID,IX_umbracoNodeObjectType,IX_cmsContentType,IX_cmsContentType_icon,IX_cmsTemplate_nodeId,IX_cmsContent,IX_cmsContentVersion_ContentId,IX_cmsContentVersion_VersionId,IX_cmsDocument,IX_cmsDocument_published,IX_cmsDocument_newest,IX_cmsDataType_nodeId,IX_cmsDictionary_id,IX_umbracoLanguage_languageISOCode,IX_umbracoLog,IX_cmsMacroPropertyAlias,IX_cmsMacroProperty_Alias,IX_cmsPropertyTypeGroupUniqueID,IX_cmsPropertyTypeUniqueID,IX_cmsPropertyData,IX_cmsPropertyData_1,IX_cmsPropertyData_2,IX_cmsPropertyData_3,IX_cmsTags,IX_umbracoUser_userLogin,IX_cmsTaskType_alias,IX_umbracoAccess_nodeId,IX_umbracoAccessRule,IX_umbracoMigration,IX_umbracoDeployChecksum,IX_umbracoRedirectUrl


 2016-11-28 22:31:20,924 [P1436/D4/T19] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Installation step DatabaseUpgrade failed.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallException: The database failed to upgrade. ERROR: The database configuration failed with the following message: Invalid object name 'cmsContent'.
 Please check log file for additional information (can be found in '/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt')
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseUpgradeStep.Execute(Object model)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.ExecuteStep(InstallSetupStep step, JToken instruction)
 2016-11-28 22:31:20,925 [P1436/D4/T19] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 737ms)
 2016-11-28 22:31:20,925 [P1436/D4/T19] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - An error occurred during installation step DatabaseUpgrade
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallException: The database failed to upgrade. ERROR: The database configuration failed with the following message: Invalid object name 'cmsContent'.
 Please check log file for additional information (can be found in '/App_Data/Logs/UmbracoTraceLog.txt')
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseUpgradeStep.Execute(Object model)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.ExecuteStep(InstallSetupStep step, JToken instruction)
   at Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController.PostPerformInstall(InstallInstructions installModel)
 2016-11-28 22:31:43,882 [P1436/D3/T19] INFO  Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - Application shutdown. Details: ConfigurationChange

_shutDownMessage=CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWithoutDemand()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.OnConfigurationChanged(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigChanged(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.OnStreamChanged(String streamname)
   at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHostFileChange.OnFileChanged(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Comment: Have any tables been created in your database?  Perhaps check the database permissions of the IIS web user and ensure they are at least 'ddladmin' & 'securityadmin'.  When developing locally, I just add 'db_owner'.

Comment: @Sambo Good idea to check, but one table has created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to start with an empty connection string in the web.config and set up an empty SQL database. During the installation of Umbraco choose Customize and fill in the details of the empty database you created using the Microsoft SQL Server database type.

So, your connection string before you start needs to look like this:

`<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="" providerName="" />`

It is also important the the `umbracoConfigurationStatus` value is blank, like so:

`<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="" />`

Then configure your SQL server as SQL server, not as "Custom connection string":

[image]

Fill in the details like you need them to be and enable "Use integrated authentication".

Comment: Please read my edited version of question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @serefbilge Updated my answer too. For some reason your connection string didn't work, don't know why.

Comment: It might work if you add the driver to the custom connection string and/or using `Trusted_Connection` instead of `Integrated Security`: `Driver=Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;`

Comment: Good advice, I tried as 'database type: microsoft sql server' in installation part(as you recommended) and create a database having a collation without '_SC' flag which is 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS'; then installation is finished properly. Thanks.